# Inconsistencies with double data type in C++

Tags: c++, types, double

This may be something really simple that I'm just missing, however I am having trouble using the double data type. It states [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that a double in C++ is accurate to ~15 digits. Yet in the code:

```
double n = pow(2,1000);
cout << fixed << setprecision(0) << n << endl;
```

n stores the exact value of 2^1000, something that is 302 decimal digits long according to WolframAlpha. Yet, when I attempt to compute 100!, with the function:

```
   double factorial(int number)
{
    double product = 1.0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++){product*=i;}
    return product;
}
```

Inaccuracies begin to appear at the 16th digit. Can someone please explain this behaviour, as well as provide me with some kind of solution.

Thanks

Comment: there's nothing to solve this is as designed.

Comment: Do a web search for "IEEE 754" and **read**.

Comment: No, the page says nothing about double being accurate at all. It just says how much numbers it can span. Accuracy is all about how floating point works.

Comment: First you said "It states here that a double in C++ is accurate to ~15 digits." and then you said "Inaccuracies begin to appear at the 16th digit. Can someone please explain this behaviour". Haven't you already answered your own question? Roughly it could be said that the double data type can store ~15 digits "effectively" but then it can store even more if lots of them are zeros.

Comment: IEEE 754 uses a scientific-notation system. It stores the number and the exponent. So it can "tore even more if lots of them are zeros" only if they are trailing 0's

Comment: @kynnysmatto if you go to wolframalpha and type in 2^1000 you will see that it is a 302 digit number with hardly any continuous sets of zeroes.

Comment: @njak32 You're right that it's a 302 digit number with hardly any sets of zeros __in decimal system__. But since computers use binary system, the number 2^1000 is only "1" followed by one thousand zeros.

Comment: @kyn: You mean a 1 followed by 1111101000 zeros, right? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need eventually to read the basics in [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://dlc.sun.com/pdf/800-7895/800-7895.pdf).  The most common standard for floating-point hardware is generally IEEE 754; the current version is from 2008, but most CPUs do not implement the new decimal arithmetic featured in the 2008 edition.

However, a floating point number (`double` or `float`) stores an approximation to the value, using a fixed-size mantissa (fractional part) and an exponent (power of 2).  The dynamic range of the exponents is such that the values that can be represented range from about 10<sup>-300</sup> to 10<sup>+300</sup> in decimal, with about 16 significant (decimal) digits of accuracy.  People persistently try to print more digits than can be stored, and get interesting and machine-dependent (and library-dependent) results when they do.

So, what you are seeing is intrinsic to the nature of floating-point arithmetic on computers using fixed-precision values.  If you need greater precision, you need to use one of the arbitrary-precision libraries - there are many of them available.

Answer (score 3):

The double actually stores an exponent to be applied to 2 in it's internal representation. So of course it can store 2^1000 accurately.  But try adding 1 to that.

Answer (score 2):

[IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) gives an algorithm for storing floating point data. Computers have a finite number of bits to store an infinite number of numbers, and thus introduces error when storing digits.

In this form of representation, there is less room for precision the larger the represented number gets (larger == absolute distance from zero).  Probably at that point you are seeing the loss of precision, and as you get even larger numbers, it will have even larger loss of precision.

Comment: nonsense! This is floating point. What has distance from zero got to do with it?

Comment: @David: Everything? The further away from zero a number is, the greater the delta to the next representable number.

Comment: @Fred So how come the number with 300 decimal digits is represented exactly? By this so-called logic that would not be possible because all the precision has been lost because of the great distance from zero.

Comment: @David: when you get a 1*2^300 carried in a `double` you don't know if it was actually a binary 1 followed by 300 zeroes or it was a 1 followed by 50 zeroes and then all ones. The precision of the type do not allow you to know that; if it was a 1 followed by 300 zeroes you've been lucky (since your result is represented exactly), but you don't even know it for sure (since you have a +-2^something uncertainty).

Comment: i suppose it depends whether you are in the business of adding or multiplying